# Android Studio not building or running my project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I just downloaded Android Studio and I chose the empty template, so there is not anything I have added to the code.
The problem is when I run the app on an external device or build it, it doesnt work and it gives me an error.
`` Cause: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "bb`fc`acaacgGMT+00:00" ``
I searched for answers on the site and I found someone who said: "try to delete the .gradle folder"
I did that and still not working.
What should I do ?
[Thats the message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlMb8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to go on your system setting to time & langauge ->Date & time:
set time zone auto and the time auto

Comment: it did not work

Comment: I hope it'll work language, date & time changing something project settings.  https://youtu.be/Gz5u0jeaB8k

Comment: did you enaled the time zone auto??